# Thread safety writing in a map

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a block of code provided below:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> salesMap = new HashMap<>();

orderItems.parallelStream().forEach(orderItem -> {

            synchronized (this) {

                int itemId = orderItem.getItemId();
                Item item = settingsClient.getItemByItemId(itemId);

                String revenueCenterName = itemIdAndRevenueCenterNameMap.get(itemId);
                updateSalesMap(salesMap, "Gross Sales: " + revenueCenterName, orderItem.getNetSales().toPlainString());

            }
});


private void updateSalesMap(Map<String,BigDecimal> salesMap, String key, String amount) {

        BigDecimal bd = getSalesAmount(salesMap, key);
        int scale = 2;

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(amount)) {
            amount = "0.00";
        }

        BigDecimal addMe = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(amount)).setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        salesMap.put(key, bd.add(addMe));
    }
```

The code works fine, but if I don't use the `synchronized` block, it will end of varying data in the map. As far I know, the streams are thread safe, so I get curious about whats happening. I tried to use ConcurrentHashMap but it seems nothing changed.

My idea is the map data is not written in the RAM and read/ write is done in the thread cache and hence, we end up having various data.

Is it correct? If so, I will use `volatile` keyword then using a synchronized block.

Note: just find that I cant declare a variable `volatile` inside a method.

Comment: `.parallelStream().forEach(i -> synchronized(this) { ... })` so you're using multithreading to force everything to run one after another? Rather than using streams for side effects, especially multithreaded ones, you should use them to _produce_ the results you're looking for, and operate on them after.

Comment: so you're using multithreading to force everything to run one after another?  > Correct. 
Can you write example code? Thanks.

Comment: If that's your actual goal, don't multithread them. You're just wasting CPU

Comment: The question is why you are running a parallel stream if you want your changes to be serial.

Comment: It's a really big list with multiple sections of the operations inside and running parallel makes it significantly faster.

Comment: Put the `synchronized (this)` only around the `updateSalesMap` call. Or, even, just around the `salesMap.put` call.

Comment: @AndyTurner Synchronizing `salesMap.put` won't help here - in `updateSalesMap` there might be old value of `bd` which is read in first line of the method.

Comment: Learn to use the Stream API correctly, i.e. how to use `map` and `collect` to perform your task, instead of writing a loop in disguise with `forEach`. Then, you get high performance *and* correctness. Your code would also benefit from converting the `String` to `BigDecimal` directly, instead of going the `double` detour.

Comment: The entire operation can be implemented as `Map<String, BigDecimal> salesMap = orderItems.parallelStream() .collect(Collectors.toMap( orderItem -> "Gross Sales: " + itemIdAndRevenueCenterNameMap.get(orderItem.getItemId()), orderItem -> orderItem.getNetSales(), BigDecimal::add));`—Thread safe without additional synchronization. It omits the `settingsClient.getItemByItemId(itemId)` call whose return value you are not using, as well as the `BigDecimal`→`String`→`double`→`BigDecimal`→“rounded `BigDecimal`” detour. This may already gain more performance than parallel processing.

Comment: @Holger I have many similar operations inside the synchronized block that I havent provided in the example code in question. So how doesn it still fit with my code?

Furthermore, this code also doesnt look very readable to me (sorry)

Comment: Of course, code posted in a comment doesn’t look readable. You have to copy it into your code base and format appropriately. It is possible to insert more code into these functions, but on the other hand, it seems you shouldn’t do what you are doing here at all. If these other operations need synchronization, you have simply asked the wrong question. But since you’ve accepted an answer that suggests to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` without synchronization, it’s rather surprising that you suddenly need other operations to be within the same synchronized block.

Comment: I use the code that I write an answer later on. and I had many operations 20-25 in that block but it not readable to put WHOLE codebase when asking a question to the SOF. But I appreciate your effort to provide a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far I know, the streams are thread safe, so I get curious about whats happening.

They are. As long as you only operate on the stream itself. The problem is that you try to manipulate other variable at the same time (map in this case). The idea of streams is that operations on each of elements are totally independent - check idea of funcional programming.

> I tried to use `ConcurrentHashMap` but it seems nothing changed.

The issue comes from your approach. The general idea is that atomic operations on `ConcurrentHashMap` are thread safe. However, if you perform two thread safe operations together, it won't be atomic and thread safe. You need to synchronize it yourself or come up with some other solution.

In `updateSalesMap()` method you first get value from the map, do some calculations and then update the value. This sequence of operations isn't atomic - performing them on `ConcurrentHashMap` won't change much.

One of possible ways to achieve concurrency in this case would be to utilize `CuncurrentHashMap.compute()` [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing *read* operation using `getSalesAmount(salesMap, key)` and *write* operation using `salesMap.put(key, bd.add(addMe))`, in separate statements. The non-atomicity of this breakup of these operations is not going to change, irrespective of the kind of Map, you use. The `synchronized` block will solve this ofcourse.

Alternatively, You can use `ConcurrentHashMap`'s `compute(K key, BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction)`, for the kind of atomicity, you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I make the updateSalesMap thread-safe and that works for me:

```
protected synchronized void updateSalesMap(Map<String, BigDecimal> salesMap, String s, String amount) {

        BigDecimal bd = updateSalesAmount(salesMap, s);
        int scale = 2;

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(amount)) {
            amount = "0.00";
        }

        BigDecimal addMe = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(amount)).setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        salesMap.put(s, bd.add(addMe));
    }
```